# "Which hers was" OR "which was hers"

Tags: word-order, reported-speech

if i want to convert :

> She said, "I don't remember which is mine"

to reported speech , 
which one of these is correct ?

> She couldn't remember **which was hers**.

OR

> She couldn't remember **which hers was**.

In case both are correct , which one is more suitable?

Comment: You can also say **which one hers was** or **which one was hers**, as you do when asking your question.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this example:

> She couldn't remember **which purse was hers**.

What it says is that there were a number of purses and one of them was hers, but she couldn't remember which one was it. Do you agree that this example sounds like perfectly valid English? I hope you do because it is perfectly valid English. Now, *"She couldn't remember which hers was."*, with respect to the example that I just showed you, would actually be equivalent to the following:

> She couldn't remember **which purses was**.

I hope you can see that there are a lot of problems with the English here. First of all, since *purses* is a word that's in the plural, the past-tense form of the verb *to be* must also be in its plural form to agree with *purses*: *were*. Secondly, wouldn't you say that *which purses were* would now sound like an incomplete thought? Were the purses hers or were the purses lost? What exactly was happening with them? Not clear at all. And *hers* in your original example sounds like the plural form of the noun *her* as there were such a noun. What exactly is a *her*? Is there really such a noun in English? I don't think so. So, to cut a long story short, your second example grammatically is just a catastrophe. Only your first example is correct:

> She couldn't remember **which was hers**.

Comment: Could you please explain why does "which hers was" becomes equivalent to "which purses was " wrt the example you gave. Shouldn't it be equivalent to "she couldn't remember which her purse was" ?

Comment: **which her purse was** is, practically speaking, an impossible construction. Do you understand that you have two determiners for the word **purse** in this example? It should be either **which** or **her**, but not both at the same time. It's kind of like saying **my her purse**. **Which** is as much a determiner as **her**, **his** or **their** are. Do you understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: *She thought and thought and scratched her head and thought some more, but she couldn't remember which hers was* is not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I hope you will explain where and how I am wrong.

Comment: One of them may be a more straightforward representation of reported speech, if we admit "couldn't remember" as invoking reported speech. But both utterances (**which hers was** and **which was hers**) are grammatical.  You claimed that **which hers was** is equivalent to the ungrammatical "She couldn't remember which purses was."  but that is not so.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, I claimed that and I gave my reasons why I think it's ungrammatical. You claim the opposite, yet you're not baking it up with an explanation. No offense, but why should I believe you?

Comment: Consider a young girl who is given a puppy at the dog breeders. She has been petting it for only a moment when she turns away for a second, and it runs back to the litter, where now there are eight identical puppies. She could look and look, and be unable to say **which hers *was***.  It is a form of emphasis.  Perfectly legit in my neck of the woods.

Comment: Sounds like nonstandard English. Something that's perfectly legit in your neck of the woods might not be in somebody else's.

Comment: How about *One of them is mine, but I'm unable to say which.*

Comment: "She couldn't remember who John was" and "She couldn't remember who was John" are both perfectly good English sentences, even though they mean slightly different things. Ditto for the OP's sentences.